# Ошибка сегментации в linked list

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, linked-list

Есть функция deleteLast, которая удаляет **первый** элемент linkedlist'а.

Есть код:

```
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::deleteLast()
{
    Node* nemp= head;//head- это указатель на объект класса Node
    while(nemp)//пока указатель не будет указывать на nullptr
        if(nemp->next->next==nullptr)//если укзатель next'а next указывает nullptr
            {
                delete nemp->next->next;
                nemp->next=nullptr;
                size--;
            }
        else
            nemp=nemp->next;
}
```

при runtime выдает ошибку сегментации. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 4):

Вы обращаетесь к `nemp->next->next`, где `nemp->next` может быть `nullptr`. Поэтому и получаете такую ошибку.

Возможный способ исправления: добавить в начало if проверку `nemp->next != nullptr` или просто `nemp->next`.

Comment: Спасибо, но теперь цикл while не оставливается

Comment: @RoarRaizZer возможно и такое. Но это уже другой вопрос. Могу посоветовать хранить предыдущий и текущий узлы. Тогда проход будет элементарным и удалить последний получится через указатель на предыдущий